# Editing files in /var/www

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, filesystems

I know that the owner of the files in `/var/www` must be `www-data` to properly run by apache. But when i run the `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` command i can't the php files in my editor.

How can i edit the files without messing the permissions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take care of ownership:

```
chown -hR www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Ensure the group can read and write the files. This *does not* enable it to alter any permissions though:

```
chmod  -R g+rw /var/www
```

The `x` bit. Ensure the group is permitted to list the directories, but not to execute the files:

```
find /var/www -type d -ls -exec chmod g+x {} ';'
```

Add yourself to the group www-data so you can use the permissions of this group:

```
usermod -aG www-data your-user
```

Comment: +1 and you can also set `x` for directories only with `chmod -R g+rwX /var/www` (capital X) on the second step and discard 3rd command

Answer (score 2):

The owner of the files does not have be `www-data` for `apache` to work well.  The requirement is that the `apache` server which runs as `www-data` must be able to read the files.  Most systems default to allowing group read access, so having the group on the files be `www-data` is sufficient.

The `apache` server needs to be able to write dynamic content such as wikis, content upload directories, and caches.   Otherwise it is more secure to prevent the `apache` server from writing its content directories and files.

Consider changing the ownership to the user who needs to modify the content.  Add them to the group `www-data`.   You could also set the group sticky bit on the /var/www directory.  If you are the user you can execute these commands.

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
sudo usermod -aG www-data $LOGNAME
sudo chown -R $LOGNAME /var/www
```

Logout and login again to gain access to the www-data group.  You will then be able to modify the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod  766 /var/www  -R
```

This will give write permission to your user.

Comment: This will give `rwx` to user (www-data), `rw` to group (www-data) and `r  to others. This won't work to write the file with another user than www-data

Comment: My bad , i have updated the answer.

Comment: Now ok for the access but this will make all the files readable and writable by any user which is not good for security - downvote removed as it works but this is not secure

Comment: then make chmod 760 and add yourself to www-data group as a member