# Unable to access /var/www/sugarcrm/custom/Extension with www-data ownership

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, file-permissions, apache-http-server, sugarcrm

I've been working with SugarCRM Community 6.5 in an Ubuntu 12.04 development environment to do some testing before moving to production. I am using Apache 2, PHP5 and MySQL to run SugarCRM. I have been able to install SugarCRM, but need to access /var/www/sugarcrm/custom/Extension to be able to make some changes to a module using a PHP script. The installation directions I followed required me to change ownership of the SugarCRM files in the sugarcrm folder to www-data, but I kept the group as root. When I try to access the Extension folder in the file GUI in Ubuntu I get a permission denied message: 
"The folder contents could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "Extension".

I have done some searching and tried the suggestions in the following post:

[Editing files in /var/www](https://superuser.com/questions/378412/editing-files-in-var-www)

But I am still receiving the same error message, so I changed ownership back to the root group. Apache would not serve up the SugarCRM files without www-data ownership, so I kept ownership to www-data. My file permissions are as follows--

Contents of /var/www:

```
myuser@ubuntu:/var/www$ list
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  9 22:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Jul  9 16:38 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  177 Jul  9 16:38 index.html
drwxrwxr-x 19 www-data root     4096 Jul  9 23:06 sugarcrm
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   20 Jul  9 18:10 testphp.php
```

Contents of sugarcrm:

```
myuser@ubuntu:/var/www/sugarcrm/custom$ list
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data root 4096 Jul  9 23:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 19 www-data root 4096 Jul  9 23:06 ..
drwxrws---  3 www-data root 4096 Jul  9 23:14 application
drwxrws---  3 www-data root 4096 Jul  9 23:14 Extension
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data root   55 Jun 21 01:01 index.html
drwxrws---  9 www-data root 4096 Jul  9 23:14 modules
```

Should I be applying these changes to /var/www/ instead of just the sugarcrm files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add yourself to the www-data group

> sudo usermod -aG www-data `<USERNAME>`

and set the user and group to www-data on the sugarcrm folder

> sudo chown www-data:www-data `<FOLDER>`

then chmod it

> sudo chmod u=rX,g=rwX,o=rX `<FOLDER>`

and then do the folders that sugar needs to be able to write to

> sudo chmod u+w `<FOLDER>` `<OTHER FOLDER\>` `<...>`

you may have to log out and back in for this to take effect